# Why does my property have a line through it on intellisense?

Tags: c#, class, properties, intellisense

When i access a property through intellisense, sometimes it has a line through it like so :

[image]

Why is this happening? is it deprecated?

Comment: Yes, it is deprectated.

Comment: I've not seen this with a line through the intellisense item. Is there a setting that does this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're deprecated or obsolete. They exist for backwards compatibility.

In your particular example, it's advised to use [ConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) instead. [See the Remarks for ConfigurationSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationsettings.aspx).

Answer (score 10):

It is deprecated (obsolete), as you can see from its [documentation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationsettings.appsettings.aspx) where it is marked with the `ObsoleteAtrribute`.

You should instead use `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`.